# Como hacer un loop para preguntar un input entre 2 a 10 y que no sea string? (Java)

Tags: java

Me gustaría encontrar la forma de preguntarle al usuario que inserte un número entre 2 y 10, si el usuario inserta otro número distinto que de error y que lo vuelva a preguntar y si el usuario inserta una letra que también de error y vuelva a preguntar.
Yo lo que he podido hacer y lo que he encontrado son varias maneras, pero por un lado da error en el sentido de que detecta que no esta entre esas cifras te da un mensaje de error e insertas una letra y no vuelve a loop.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //kb = keyboard (teclado)
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean out = true;
        //n = number
        int n = 0;

        //loop
        while (out) {
            System.out.println("Inserta un número entre 2 y 10.");

            if (kb.hasNextInt()) {
                n = kb.nextInt();
                if ((n >= 2 && n <= 10)) {
                    out = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Por favor inserta solo entre 2 y 10");
                    kb.next();
                }
                out = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No es un número, vuele a intentarlo!");
                kb.next();
            }
        }
        out = true;
    }
}
```

Otra solución encontrada en foros sería esta... pero hagas el error que hagas siempre te dice la misma frase.

```
do {
    System.out.print("Choose a number between[2-10]");

    while(!kb.hasNextInt()){
        kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("It's not a valid number.");             
    }
    n = kb.nextInt();
} while ((v<=1 || v>=11));
```

Y por último otra solución más compleja sería esta

```
    final Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer temp = null;

    while (temp == null) {
      System.out.println("Enter a number between 2 and 10.");
      final String input = kb.nextLine();
    try {
     final Integer value = Integer.valueOf(input);
     if (value >= 2 && value < 10) {
        temp = value;
     } else {
        System.out.println("Bad number, try again");
     }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      System.out.println("Not a number, try again");
    }
    }
    int n = temp;
```

A ver que solución posible se puede encontar.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te pongo otra solución mas clara y al grano según lo que tu estas hablando:

> Me gustaría encontrar la forma de preguntarle al usuario que inserte un número entre 2 y 10, si el usuario inserta otro número distinto que de error y que lo vuelva a preguntar y si el usuario inserta una letra que también de error y vuelva a preguntar.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   boolean op = true;
   String val = null;
   do{
      System.out.println("Ingresa un número entre 2 y 10");
      val = in.next();
      if(Integer.valueOf(val)){
         if(val >= 2 && val <= 10){
            op = false; 
         }else{
            System.out.println("El valor ingresado no se encuentra entre los números permitidos");
         }
      }else{
           System.out.println("El valor ingresado no es un número");
      }
   }while(op);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Mi solución:

```
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = 0;
    boolean out = false;

    while (!out) {
        try {

            n = kbd.nextInt();

            if (n < 2 || n > 10) {
                System.out.println("El número debe estar entre 2 y 10");
            } else {
                out = true; // Saldrá del bucle
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) { // Si se produce esta excepción es que no ha escrito un número entero
            System.out.println("No has introducido un número");
            kbd.nextLine(); // Limpiamos el salto de línea
        }

    }
```